# NSWindow blocking the application like an Alert Panel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

is it possible to get an NSWindow to block everything in my application just like an Alert panel so that it is the key window until closed?

Comment: Yes, but please don't block the application! How many Mac applications do you know which has this blocking window? Please do it only absolutely necessary; don't replicate the feature of a Windows app which has blocking behavior.

Comment: Its for a special action window like NSAlertPanel ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alert is a simple modal window, you can run yours with

[NSApp runModalForWindow: myNSWindow];